# ActiveRecord serialize sending nil to custom serializer for present attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I have the following custom serializer:

```
class ReportCardDataSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.to_json
  end

  def self.load(json)
    # json.class == NilClass, why????
    hash = (json || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

And the following class with a serialized `data` attribute with database column set to NOT NULL.

```
class ReportCardGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, ReportCardDataSerializer # data is PostgreSQL jsonb column
end
```

The ReportCardDataSerializer `dump` method works as expected. But on trying to `load` ReportCardDataSerializer `load` method gets sent nil even though the database column is not nil.

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you test your serializer on a different column or rename `data` to exclude that this is due to a "reserved" column name (like if `type` is used as column which is reserved for polymorphism)

Comment: @jethroo Renamed the column, same issues.

Comment: Why are you using serialize for a Postgres native JSON column? If you want it as `with_indifferent_access` just create a getter instead.

Comment: @max I need to post-process the JSON to convert BigDecimals that have been converted to JSON string back to BigDecimal

Comment: I have never actually written a custom encoder but if you look at the built in [`ActiveRecord::Coders::JSON`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activerecord/lib/active_record/coders/json.rb) the `.load` method is passed a raw string and not the unencoded object. As to why it is nil it would be helpful if you can show exactly how you have tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by going through the ActiveRecord serialization class.

ActiveRecord serializer calls `type_cast_from_database`:

```
def type_cast_from_database(value)
    if default_value?(value)
      value
    else
      coder.load(super)
    end
end

def default_value?(value)
    value == coder.load(nil) # HERE: Calls Serializer with nil
end
```

I assumed ReportCardDataSerializer would never have to process nil, but ActiveRecord actually first tries loading nil to test for the default value.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to figure how to fix the issue?

Comment: Yea, my answer explains how I "fixed" it. Although it was really broken in my case.